# Excel calculation suffix

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet with 3 side dimensions of a package.
[dimension column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM3Ud.jpg)

Is there a way to get the multiplied value of these dimensions? There are hundred of rows, manually would take too much time.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that how the values appear in a cell?

Comment: This solution will need some VBA code, that's why I edited tags

Comment: @MichałTurczyn VBA might be a way to go here, but why not just reimport and separate out the three values?

Comment: You can use evalute, e.g. `evaluate("="&range("A1"))`.

Answer (score 1):

Or write a simple UDF to do the Evaluate on the string. If you set your data up as a table then the UDF will be automatically filled down as many rows as required.

In a standard module

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetSum(ByVal myRange As Range) As Long
    GetSum = Evaluate(myRange.Value)
End Function
```

[image: Output]

Similar idea was discussed here:

https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula

And a quick and dirty version where you can specify the delimiter e.g. "*" or something else that separates the numbers

```
Public Function GetSum2(ByVal myRange As Range, ByVal delimiter As String) As Long

    Dim myArr() As String

    myArr = Split(myRange.Value, delimiter)

    Dim outputValue As Long
    outputValue = 1

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        outputValue = outputValue * CLng(myArr(i))
    Next i

    GetSum2 = outputValue

End Function
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the separator is actually an asterisk.

Comment: What sharp eyes you have!

Comment: This is a good answer, surely useful to someone who needs a VBA solution +1.

Comment: This seems to be one of those situations in which it is necessary to specify the Value property. `Evaluate(Range("A1"))` doesn't work, although `Evaluate("=" & Range("A1"))` does.

Comment: As SJR agreed. That is why I used myRange.Value. Have I missed a trick please?

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate function works , but it needs a few steps to get it working, you can't just put into the cell as in =Evaluate($A1)
You need to setup a named range first

Select cell B1

Go to the FORMULAS tab and click Define Name

In the dialog box, type in a name like Result

In the Refers to box, put in the formula =Evaluate($A1)

Click OK
Now in B1 type in =Result

You can drag this down for all cells.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have 3-digit numbers, then this Array Formula will work (Remember that you need to hit [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to convert from Formula to Array Formula)

```
=PRODUCT(0+(MID(B1,1+(4*(ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,1+LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"*","")),1))-1)),3)))
```

Annoyingly, `MID` doesn't work on arrays in a `SUMPRODUCT`, so this needs to be a proper Array Formula :(

The `B1` is the cell with the numbers in, `$A$1` is just to make sure that we pull out enough 3-digit numbers (leave it on Row 1!), and `"*"` should be the deliminator character

Comment: Cool formula!.............................we could also multiply 3 `MID()`s

Comment: My formula allows any number of numbers to be multiplied, but only if they are 3-digit. @ScottCraner's answer multiplies 3 numbers, regardless of digits.  If you replaced his `ROW(1:3)` with my `ROW(OFFSET($A$1,0,0,1+LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"*","")),1))` then you get the general case for any number of numbers of any number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
=PRODUCT(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"*",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW(1:3)-1)*999+1,999)))
```

As an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option here is probably to save your current worksheet as a CSV text file.  Then reimport this file using the diamond symbol in your screen capture as a delimiter.  This will place each of the three values in separate columns.  Once you get this far, you may simply take the product of the three columns.

Comment: you can skip the export and import and just use Text to Columns.

Comment: @ScottCraner I never knew about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub CalculateVolumes()
Dim column As Long, lastRow As Long, i As Long, number As Variant, volume As Long
column = 1 'A column
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastRow
    volume = 1
    For Each number In Split(Cells(i, column).Value, "*")
        volume = volume * number
    Next
    'column + 1 means that I will put calculated volume next to the cell
    Cells(i, column + 1).Value = volume
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA

with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"*",REPT(" ",999)),999-998,999))*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"*",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"*",REPT(" ",999)),3*999-998,999))
```

[image]